# Whats wrong with this jquery variable

Tags: jquery

I'm kinda new to Jquery but doing my best to be better.

I have a problem with a variable, so would like to have some help. Have tried and search the web for hours but can't get it to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(){
        var lek = "http://dif.se/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/bortajersey_topp.jpg";
        $(".contact").slideDown();
        var imageurl = $(".contact").text($("img", this).attr("src"));
        $(this).add("img",this).css("background", "yellow");
        $(".contact").append("<img src="+imageurl+">");
    });
});
```

The variable I have problems with is the imageurl, I get it to work just as I want with the "lek" variable.

Thanks guys,
Michael

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please clarify it and explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Wondered what was wrong with my "imageurl" variable, and got the right answer. The HTML mark-up works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imageurl` contains a jQuery object (since most jQuery calls are [chainable](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/quick-guide-chaining-in-jquery/)). This line:

```
var imageurl =  $(".contact").text($("img", this).attr("src"));
```

is effectively equivalent to.:

```
var imageurl =  $(".contact");
imageurl.text($("img", this).attr("src"));
```

Try this instead:

```
var imageurl = $("img", this).attr("src"); // imageurl is a string
$(".contact").text(imageurl);
```

Comment: Wow, that was a quick answer! :) And it solved my problem! Thank you so much Paul!